# How to remove black borders around License Plate using opencv for android app

Tags: android, opencv

I want to remove black borders around License Plate. I am using opencv + android.
Please reply with code using which i can remove the borders.

I have also attached the image.[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEmgZ.jpg)

Comment: Can you upload the original image? Try canny edge detection otherwise by choosing optimal threshold values...

Comment: I have uploaded the original image here https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfIsY.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can perform (DoG) Difference of Gaussians to detect the high frequency details in your image. By high frequency in an image I mean distinct **edges** and **corners**.

Here is the code as requested. The explanations are placed as comments by the side:

```
import cv2                      
img = cv2.imread('number_plate.jpg')     #---Reading the image---   
img1 = img.copy()    #----The final contour will be drawn on the copy of the original image--- 
gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)   #---converting to gray scale---
```

Before performing DoG, I enhanced the gray sale image by applying **Adaptive histogram equalization**:

```
clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=3.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
enhanced = clahe.apply(gray_img)
cv2.imshow(enhanced_gray_img', enhanced)
```

[image]

Now I performed **Gaussian blur** using two separate kernels and subtracted the resulting images as follows:

```
blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(enhanced, (15, 15), 0)
blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(enhanced, (25, 25), 0)
difference = blur2 - blur1
cv2.imshow('Difference_of_Gaussians', difference)
```

[image]

Then I performed binary threshold on the image above and found contours. I drew the contour having the largest area:

```
ret, th = cv2.threshold(difference, 127,255, 0)    #---performed binary threshold ---

_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(th, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 1)    #---Find contours---
cnts = contours
max = 0    #----Variable to keep track of the largest area----
c = 0      #----Variable to store the contour having largest area---
for i in range(len(contours)):
    if (cv2.contourArea(cnts[i]) > max):
        max = cv2.contourArea(cnts[i])
        c = i

rep = cv2.drawContours(img1, contours[c], -1, (0,255,0), 3)    #----Draw the contour having the largest area on the image---
cv2.imshow('Final_Image.jpg', rep)
```

[image]

And voila!!! There you go.

Now you can obtain bounding rectangles for the contours you found and fed those coordinates as regions to the OCR to extract the text present

Comment: thanks a lot. Please can you provide code for android.I am a newbie, so please provide code for android.

Comment: I have never worked with Android, so I am sorry. Check out tutorials for the same [here on GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/android)

Comment: Can u plz provide your complete code using which you achieved this result? I will try to convert your code into android. Plz provide your complete code.

Comment: I have the code @home. Right now I am at work. I will post it once I get back

Comment: I followed you steps but I am getting largest contour somewhere else in the image instead of getting around the license plate.Can you help?

Comment: try inverting the binary image before finding contour

Comment: okkk........i finally got the contour around license plate. I also drew a bounded rectangle around the contour. Can you please tell me how to extract the contour around license plate ?

Comment: Since you have drawn the bounding rectangle, you now have the 4 corners with you. Crop the image using the 4 points

Comment: how to crop it? any idea? because i m drawing bounding rectangle based on area range between 2500 to 5000.So how to crop it?

Comment: Rect brect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(contourIdx));                                           
Imgproc.drawContours(img1, contours, contourIdx, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 0); // draw contours                                                                             double area = brect.width*brect.height;//  area of brect                           if ( area <= 5000 && area >= 2500 )
Core.rectangle(img1, brect.tl(), brect.br(), new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 3, 8, 0);

Comment: Here, u caan see from the above code, that using area of brect i have drawn a rectangle but i dont have any coordinates of rectangle. Do you have any idea how to crop the image and get only license plate area around which rectangle is drawn ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!! While obtaining bounding box, the function also stores the coordinates of the rectangle. Use that to crop your image. As I said, I do not know how it is done in Android

Comment: thanks.....it helped !!! I finally cropped the image and obtained the license plate area but i am getting black borders around license plate. Is there any way by which i can remove or crop the black borders around license plate image ??

Comment: WOW great to hear that. Can you upload that image by editing your question?

Comment: This problem seems to be really hard. I will post an answer if I am able to get one, until then you can try focusing your ROI (region of interest) a few pixels away from the edges of the image. You will have to write some code for that.